# jsgrid function call issue

Tags: jquery, jsgrid

So I wrapped a function around the jsGrid Data Manipulation example and had it loads based onChange event.  It works the first try but failed the second event change.  Everything is wrapped inside a function so it should be reinitialized for a second time around.  Is there something in memory that I have to purge?

http://jsfiddle.net/stevehn/ntjnnh4y/

```
    <select name="formNumber" id="numberID">
    <option value="">Select number</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

 $( "#detailsDialog" ).hide();
```

$( "#numberID" ).change(function() {

```
        $("#jsGrid").jsGrid({
            height: "70%",
            width: "100%",
            editing: true,
            autoload: true,
            paging: true,
            deleteConfirm: function(item) {
                return "The client \"" + item.Name + "\" will be removed. Are you sure?";
            },
            rowClick: function(args) {
                showDetailsDialog("Edit", args.item);
            },
            controller: db,
            fields: [
                { name: "Name", type: "text", width: 150 },
                { name: "Age", type: "number", width: 50 },
                { name: "Address", type: "text", width: 200 },
                { name: "Country", type: "select", items: db.countries, valueField: "Id", textField: "Name" },
                { name: "Married", type: "checkbox", title: "Is Married", sorting: false },
                {
                    type: "control",
                    modeSwitchButton: false,
                    editButton: false,
                    headerTemplate: function() {
                        return $("<button>").attr("type", "button").text("Add")
                            .on("click", function () {
                                showDetailsDialog("Add", {});
                            });
                    }
                }
            ]
        });

        $("#detailsDialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 400,
            close: function() {
                $("#detailsForm").validate().resetForm();
                $("#detailsForm").find(".error").removeClass("error");
            }
        });

        $("#detailsForm").validate({
            rules: {
                name: "required",
                age: { required: true, range: [18, 150] },
                address: { required: true, minlength: 10 },
                country: "required"
            },
            messages: {
                name: "Please enter name",
                age: "Please enter valid age",
                address: "Please enter address (more than 10 chars)",
                country: "Please select country"
            },
            submitHandler: function() {
                formSubmitHandler();
            }
        });

        var formSubmitHandler = $.noop;

        var showDetailsDialog = function(dialogType, client) {
            $("#name").val(client.Name);
            $("#age").val(client.Age);
            $("#address").val(client.Address);
            $("#country").val(client.Country);
            $("#married").prop("checked", client.Married);

            formSubmitHandler = function() {
                saveClient(client, dialogType === "Add");
            };

            $("#detailsDialog").dialog("option", "title", dialogType + " Client")
                .dialog("open");
        };

        var saveClient = function(client, isNew) {
            $.extend(client, {
                Name: $("#name").val(),
                Age: parseInt($("#age").val(), 10),
                Address: $("#address").val(),
                Country: parseInt($("#country").val(), 10),
                Married: $("#married").is(":checked")
            });

            $("#jsGrid").jsGrid(isNew ? "insertItem" : "updateItem", client);

            $("#detailsDialog").dialog("close");
        };

    });
```

Comment: When jsGrid is initialized for the second time it doesn't create new grid but just triggers massive option change. The final intension of your example is not clear. If you want to have several grids - create several divs and just show div associated with select item. If you don't want to overload page with several grids, init them on show even lazily.

Comment: I don't want to create new grid and shove it to a new div.  I just want to refresh the existing grid with new set of data.  The goal is to use the loadData function and ajax call the webservice to get different set of data based on the selection form field.
    loadData: function (filter) {
....     $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     url:"webservice?Method=getSitesWS&PlantID=" + $("#numberID").val(),
       dataType: "json"
       }).done(function(response){
         data.resolve(data);
     });
      return data.promise();
    }

Comment: ok, it's doable, but still you need to initialized stuff only once and then just change necessary options, when a value in the dropdown has been changed.